# neat way to set selected option from javascript literal

Tags: javascript, literals, html-templates

I'm trying to set the selected option using Javascript literals.

```
function getHtmlFromTask(task) {
    let markup =        
    `<select class="custom-select d-block" id="stack" value="${task.stack}" required="">
        <option value="">Choose...</option>
        <option value="java">java</option>
        <option value="go">go</option>
        <option value="python">pyhton</option>
        <option value="react">react</option>
        <option value="javascript">javascript</option>
    </select>`
    return markup
}
```

I'm currently doing the following, but is there a neater way to do this as my list will change over time?

```
<select class="custom-select d-block" id="stack" required="">
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    <option value="java"       ${task.stack.match("java") ? 'selected' : ''}>java</option>
    <option value="go"         ${task.stack.match("go") ? 'selected' : ''}>go</option>
    <option value="python"     ${task.stack.match("python") ? 'selected' : ''} >python</option>
    <option value="react"      ${task.stack.match("react") ? 'selected' : ''}>react</option>
    <option value="javascript" ${task.stack.match("javascript") ? 'selected' : ''}>javascript</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You could have a function that just builds one `option`, and pass in the value and a selected bool (or do the calculation in the function is it's always based on the value) It's debatable whether that's tidier, but it may make future changes less error prone.

Comment: yeah, thats not a bad idea. I'll have to get the full list from the server with an api call, but would work, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you separate out the creation of the `option` elements it may be clearer, here's one possible way you could go about doing that:

```js
function getHtmlFromTask(task) {
    let markup =        
    `<select class="custom-select d-block" id="stack" value="${task.stack}" required="">
        <option value="">Choose...</option>
        ${ buildOption('java', task) }
        ${ buildOption('go', task) }
        ${ buildOption('python', task) }
        ${ buildOption('react', task) }
        ${ buildOption('javascript', task) }
    </select>`
    return markup
}

function buildOption(value, task) {
  return `<option value="${value}" ${task.stack.match(value) ? 'selected' : ''}>${value}</option>`
}
```

Comment: hmm i never thought to call a function in the literal. I'll try that out thanks :)